# Changing this to a set pixel width

Tags: iphone, ios

This is probably super easy, but I can't get it to work right. I am trying to do a simple update to my iOS app by changing an image resize option to a set pixel size. the code below is what i'm working with and how it is currently functioning:

selectedWidth = (30 * selectedWidth)/100;

selectedHeight = (30 * selectedHeight)/100;

I assume this is 30% of 100%? I just need the selected width to be 200px, and height to be automatic. Can somebody please help me? I'm a newb with this type of coding, my developer is away and i thought this would be an easy change haha.

Comment: What is the current code you have there now?  And what is the result of calculation above?

Comment: so you want to change your size, width is 200px fix!? and want to calc the proportion of the height size?

Comment: that is the current code. the result is an image resized to 30% of it's original size.

Comment: yes i want the width to be 200px instead of 30%, and height auto or 100%

Answer (score 0):

So if I understand you right, I think this might help

```
selectedHeight = (selectedHeight / selectedWidth) * 200;
selectedWidth = newWidth;
```

This should calculate the correct height to your 200px width.

If you want to change your fixed-width from time to time, you can define a constant variable  in the m.file below the imports:

```
#define kWidth 200
```

and use it instead of the hard coded 200 in the code on top.

**Example:**

old width: 100px
old height: 50px

new width: 200px
new height: (50 / 100) * 200 = 100px

Comment: it's saying "use of undeclared identifier "newWidth""

Comment: thank you! its still saying newWidth is an undeclared identifier, how do i "declare" it haha. Sorry I'm so dumb at this! i'm a designer not a developer ;)

Comment: just look at my edit, make a constant variable on the top of the .m file and remove the line of "newWidth = 200;". instead of 200 you write kWidth. That's it.

Comment: Hmm ok, if i have multiple instances like this to change though that probably won't work right? for example i have to do this 4 times, i have small, medium, large, and xlarge image resizes all set up like my initial code (large for example would be 70 instead of 30).

Comment: then you should define a
kWidthSmall 40
kWidthMedium 60
and so on, and replace the constant for every of your resizes

Comment: or could i just add that define piece to set the base width and then change the other code to resize like so?:
selectedHeight = (selectedHeight / selectedWidth) * 400;

Comment: hmmm it's making them super small, like 53px wide